# live filter using underscorejs with an array of objects?

Tags: javascript, underscore.js

I am trying to filter an array depending on the name attribute typed.

```
var data = [
  {name: "Google"},
  {name: "Yahoo"}
];

var search = function(letters){
        var pattern = new RegExp(letters,"gi");
        _.filter(function(data) {
            return pattern.test(data.get("name"));
        });
};

search("yah"); // should return {name: "Yahoo"}
```

this is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

`_.filter` needs a first argument, here being your array `data` and applies a callback on each element of `data`, I think it could look like this:

```
search = function(letters){
        var pattern = new RegExp(letters,"gi");
        return _.filter(data, function(object) {
            return pattern.test(object.name);
        });
};
```